# Testing -1 over 12 anomaly with python

Tags: python, math, optimization, physics

So I saw this wonderful [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-d9mgo8FGk) made by Numberphile where they explain that if you were to add up all natural numbers you will end up with answer -1/12.

And I thought, why not to try to check it with a computer, here is a code I came up with:

```
num1 = 1
num2 = 2

while True:
    result = num1 + num2
    num1 += 1
    num2 += 1
    print(f'cycle #{num2} passed... \nresult is {len(str(result))} digits long')
    if result < 0:
        print('wtf?')
        print(f'that was loop # {num2} on which a miracle happened')
        break
```

This code has been running for around 20 minutes and Im currently on 21th million cycle and I have a feeling there must be a way to speed up these calculations, isnt it? Any ideas?

Just for the reference: Im familiar with the concept of infinity in maths, just kinda curious and will be away from my computer for a week, so why not give it a try...

Comment: It doesn't work that way.  You misunderstand what infinity means.  You can calculate what happens when you count to infinity, but you can't actually count there.  You will never add numbers up to -1/12.  Even if you leave the computer running for tens of thousands of years you will be no closer to having added up all the natural numbers than when you started.

Comment: @Delta_G well, thank you, like i said in the end, i do understand that. here is a way to think about it: its just that im willing to make my computer busy for a week and here i am asking how to speed up these calculations

Comment: Speed them up with what intent?  Getting even closer to infinity?  If you just want to see how high you can count then do that.  But that's something you can calculate.  What are you hoping to accomplish?  What do you think you can test?

Comment: And for that matter isn't the idea to add up all the natural numbers?  You're just adding two increasingly larger numbers together.  This code isn't keeping any sum value.

Answer (score 2):

It won't work numerically. To get the result as -1/12 you'll need an infinite number of natural numbers. Also, for the whole thing to work out as -1/12 you need to treat the whole series as one object, not a few terms at a time. The basic concept is that you can't halt the process in between at any term to process things. **You must have noticed it in that numberphile video also. They never treated the series term by term. Whenever they operated the series, they operated it as a whole, as a single fundamental object.** That's why this can't be implemented numerically because it is theoretical concept and different treatment of the whole infinite series that gives you the result as -1/12. Computers don't understand the infinite objects, you can't write down and store these kind of objects in memory.

Sorry if it disappointed you buddy otherwise it would really have been cool to get that result. I'm also a fan of this kind of weird maths and numberphile videos.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to make the program "correct" before trying to make it fast. Right now you are not calculating a cumulative sum 1+2+3+4+5+... but a sequence of pairwise sums 1+2, 2+3,  3+4, ...

Input/output operations like `print()` are slow. You can significantly speed up the computation by printing once every million or ten million operations, for exmaple:

```
if num2 % 1000000 == 0:
    print(f'cycle #{num2} passed... \nresult is {len(str(result))} digits long')
```

After that the next big optimization will come from switching from the CPython interpreter to something with a lower overhead (such as C, C++, PyPy, C#, Java, ...). If moving to another language, do remember that integers in Python can be arbitrarily large. In many languages you would need an external library because the "native" integer types  have size limitations.